# What is the correct way to use dplyr's slice_sample() within my apply function?

Tags: r, dplyr

In the below code, I've simulated dice rolls at increasing sample sizes and computed the average roll at each sample size. My lapply function works, but I'm uncomfortable with it since I know sample_n is not a dplyr function and has been superceded by slice_sample. I would like make my code better with a dplyr solution rather than sample_n() within the lapply. I think I may have other syntactical errors within the lapply. Here is the code:

```
   #Dice
dice <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6) #the set of possible outcomes of a dice role
dice_probs <- c(1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6) #the probability of each option per roll
dice_df <- data.frame(dice,dice_probs) 

#Simulate dice rolls for each of these sample sizes and record the average of the rolls

sample_sizes <- c(10,25,50,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,100000000) #compute at each sample size


output <- lapply(X=sample_sizes, FUN = function(var){ 
       obs = sample_n(dice_df,var,replace=TRUE) 
       sample_mean = mean(obs$dice)
       new.df <- data.frame(sample_mean, var)
      return(new.df)
            })
```

The final step is computing the difference compared to the expected value, 3.5. I want a column where that shows the difference between 3.5 and the sample mean. We should see the difference decreasing as the sample size increases.

```
output <- output %>%
      mutate(difference = across(sample_mean, ~3.5 - .x))
```

When I run this, it's throwing this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "list"
```

I've tried using sapply but I get a similar error: `no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'list')"`

---

If it helps, here was my failed attempt at using slice_sample:

```
output <- lapply(X=sample_sizes, FUN = function(...){ 
       obs = slice_sample(dice_df, ..., .preserve=TRUE) 
       sample_mean = mean(obs$dice)
       new.df <- data.frame(sample_mean, ...)
      return(new.df)
            })
```

I got this error: `Error: '...' used in an incorrect context`

Comment: you can substitute `sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), probs=c(1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6))` with `sample(1:6)`

Comment: I think you can do it with data structures simpler than data.frames, such as vectors or lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `n` argument of `slice_sample` correspondes to `sample_n`'s `size` argument.

And to calculate the difference of your `output` list we can use `purrr::map` instead of `dplyr::across`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

set.seed(123)
#Dice
dice <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6) #the set of possible outcomes of a dice role
dice_probs <- c(1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6,1/6) #the probability of each option per roll
dice_df <- data.frame(dice,dice_probs)

#Simulate dice rolls for each of these sample sizes and record the average of the rolls

sample_sizes <- c(10,25,50,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,100000000) #compute at each sample size

output <- lapply(X=sample_sizes, FUN = function(var){
  obs = slice_sample(dice_df,n  = var,replace=TRUE)
  sample_mean = mean(obs$dice)
  new.df <- data.frame(sample_mean, var)
  return(new.df)
})

output %>%
  map(~ 3.5 - .x$sample_mean)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] -0.5
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 0.42
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] -0.04
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] -0.34
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 0.025
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 0.0317
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] 0.00416
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] -2.6e-05
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] -4.405e-05
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Alternatively, we can use `purrr::map_df` and add a row `diff` inside each `tibble` as proposed by Martin Gal in the comments:

```r
output %>%
  map_df(~ tibble(.x, diff = 3.5 - .x$sample_mean))

#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   sample_mean       var       diff
#>         <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1        2.6         10  0.9      
#> 2        3.28        25  0.220    
#> 3        3.66        50 -0.160    
#> 4        3.5        100  0        
#> 5        3.53      1000 -0.0270   
#> 6        3.50     10000 -0.00180  
#> 7        3.50    100000 -0.00444  
#> 8        3.50   1000000 -0.000226 
#> 9        3.50 100000000 -0.0000669
```

Comment: As an alternative: `output %>% map_df(~ tibble(.x, diff = 3.5 - .x$sample_mean))`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I just included it in the answer.

Comment: @TimTeaFan I've tried running your solution using slice_sample but I'm getting an error: Error in sample.int(n(), check_size(~, n(), replace = replace), replace = replace,  : invalid 'size' argument

Comment: @StephenPoole: Did you run the example data above or some other data? I'm on dplyr version 1.06 and R version 4.0. I also added a `set.seed` argument to the example above, it should be reproducible given that there are no other version problems.

Answer (score 4):

The output is just a single row data.frame element in a `list`.  We can bind them with `bind_rows` and simply subtract once instead of doing this multiple times

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(output) %>% 
    mutate(difference = 3.5 - sample_mean )
  sample_mean       var  difference
1    3.500000        10  0.00000000
2    2.800000        25  0.70000000
3    3.440000        50  0.06000000
4    3.510000       100 -0.01000000
5    3.495000      1000  0.00500000
6    3.502200     10000 -0.00220000
7    3.502410    100000 -0.00241000
8    3.498094   1000000  0.00190600
9    3.500183 100000000 -0.00018332
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R way -

```
transform(do.call(rbind, output), difference = 3.5 - sample_mean)

#  sample_mean       var difference
#1        3.80        10  -0.300000
#2        3.44        25   0.060000
#3        3.78        50  -0.280000
#4        3.30       100   0.200000
#5        3.52      1000  -0.015000
#6        3.50     10000  -0.004200
#7        3.50    100000  -0.004370
#8        3.50   1000000   0.002696
#9        3.50 100000000   0.000356
```

If you just need the `difference` value you can do -

```
3.5 - sapply(output, `[[`, 'sample_mean')
```